# Dialog messages not handled when opening dialog from system tray entry

Tags: autoit

I have an AutoIt script in which I open a settings dialog from a system tray menu entry. When opening the dialog this way, messages via button clicks are not handled.

On the other hand, when opening the dialog directly (as indicated in the code below, which you can easily test by uncommenting this call and commenting out the call for the system tray entry), then the messages are handled successfully.

Here is my script. When calling `SettingsDialog` directly (without going via the systray menu), the OK and Cancel buttons work, but otherwise not.

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>

;; Start program in system tray
SetupSystemTrayEntry()

;; When calling settings dialog directly, messages are handled properly
;;SettingsDialog()


Func SetupSystemTrayEntry()
    Opt("TrayMenuMode", 1)

    $settingsitem = TrayCreateItem("Settings")
    TrayCreateItem("")
    $exititem = TrayCreateItem("Exit")

    TraySetState()

    While 1
        Local $traymsg = TrayGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $traymsg = 0
                ContinueLoop
            Case $traymsg = $settingsitem
                SettingsDialog() ;; Bring up settings dialog
            Case $traymsg = $exititem
                Exit ;; Exit program
        EndSelect
    WEnd
EndFunc

Func SettingsDialog()
    GUICreate("Settings", 400, 150, @DesktopWidth / 2 - 200, @DesktopHeight / 2 - 75)
    $ok_button = GUICtrlCreateButton("OK", 100, 100, 80, 25, $BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON)
    $cancel_button = GUICtrlCreateButton("Cancel", 200, 100, 80, 25)

    GUISetState()

    Do
        ;; These messages are never handled when the dialog is brought up from
        ;; the system tray menu entry above, but when calling this function
        ;; directly, it works
        Local $settmsg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $settmsg = $ok_button
                ExitLoop
            Case $settmsg = $cancel_button
                ExitLoop
        EndSelect
    Until $settmsg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE

EndFunc
```

Comment: I am discussing this same issue in a thread here: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/158303-dialog-messages-not-handled-when-opening-dialog-from-system-tray-entry/ . If I get it resolved, I will post the answer here.

Comment: I'm a big autoit person and love SO however I will admit it is best to ask there first. You will get a lot quicker response and usually an answer that solves your issue. I've been on those forums for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [solution provided on the AutoIt forum](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/158303-dialog-messages-not-handled-when-opening-dialog-from-system-tray-entry/#entry1148397), here is a version of the script that hides and shows the dialog on each usage. There is a big caveat (read the forum thread for details) in that on creation of the dialog, it must be explicitly hidden!

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>

; Do not declare Global variables in a function <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Global $settings_window_handle, $ok_button, $cancel_button

;; Set up settings dialog
InitSettingsDialog();

;; Start program in system tray
SetupSystemTrayEntry()

Func SetupSystemTrayEntry()
    Opt("TrayMenuMode", 1)

    $settingsitem = TrayCreateItem("Settings")
    TrayCreateItem("")
    $exititem = TrayCreateItem("Exit")

    TraySetState()

    While 1
        Switch TrayGetMsg()
            Case $settingsitem
                ShowSettingsDialog() ;; Bring up settings dialog
            Case $exititem
                Exit ;; Exit program
        EndSwitch
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>SetupSystemTrayEntry

Func InitSettingsDialog()
    ; Create
    $settings_window_handle = GUICreate("Settings", 400, 150, @DesktopWidth / 2 - 200, @DesktopHeight / 2 - 75)
    $ok_button = GUICtrlCreateButton("OK", 100, 100, 80, 25, $BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON)
    $cancel_button = GUICtrlCreateButton("Cancel", 200, 100, 80, 25)
    GUISetState(@SW_HIDE, $settings_window_handle)
EndFunc   ;==>SettingsDialog

Func ShowSettingsDialog()
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $settings_window_handle)
    While 1
        Switch GUIGetMsg()
            Case $ok_button
                MsgBox(0, "test", "test")
                ExitLoop
            Case $cancel_button
                ExitLoop
        EndSwitch
    WEnd
    GUISetState(@SW_HIDE, $settings_window_handle)
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems all fine, except you should do something after you left the Do/Until loop.

```
Func SettingsDialog()
    GUICreate("Settings", 400, 150, @DesktopWidth / 2 - 200, @DesktopHeight / 2 - 75)
    $ok_button = GUICtrlCreateButton("OK", 100, 100, 80, 25, $BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON)
    $cancel_button = GUICtrlCreateButton("Cancel", 200, 100, 80, 25)

    GUISetState()

    Do
        ;; These messages are never handled when the dialog is brought up from
        ;; the system tray menu entry above, but when calling this function
        ;; directly, it works
        Local $settmsg = GUIGetMsg()
        ConsoleWrite(@HOUR & ":" & @MIN & ":" & @SEC & "," & @MSEC & "msg = " & $settmsg & @CRLF)

        Select
            Case $settmsg = $ok_button
                ExitLoop
            Case $settmsg = $cancel_button
                ExitLoop
        EndSelect
    Until $settmsg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
    Return GUIDelete()
Endfunc
```

I added 2 lines, the `ConsoleWrite` after calling GUIGetMessage and the `Return` after the loop.

When I run this script the Settings Dialog is properly closed by either clicking 'Ok' or 'Cancel'.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution, so +1. On the AutoIt forum I found another solution which involves not deleting the dialog window each time, but just showing and hiding it, and that seems preferable. Many thanks for your help.